# Understanding namespaces and object instantiation in Joomla

Tags: joomla-4.x, namespace

PHP starts with the **index.php**, then **index.php** includes **app.php**, and then includes **framework.php**. This is where my confusion starts, maybe because of my lack of knowledge about namespaces.

In framework.php, I found:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Version;
use Joomla\Utilities\IpHelper;
```

I don't think this `Joomla\CMS\Version` namespace is just casually written, it must be referring to some code within a file, but which file and which code is still a mystery to me.

The codes below appears without a prior declaration code:

```
new Version()
IpHelper::setAllowIpOverrides(true);
```

My guess, it is related to the namespace above, but I don't know the actual relation, if my guesses are correct, how can `use Joomla\CMS\Version` logically give birth to a `new Version()`?

Answer (score 0):

The class named `Version`, the code you are looking for, is found in `..\libraries\src\Version.php`

The `use Joomla\CMS\Version` statement is the declaration or 'require_once' for the `Version` class and that makes it available for the instantiation  with the `new Version()` statement.

Any namespace prefixed with `Joomla\CMS\` can be found in `..\libraries\src`

Comment: If you are trying to find your way around the Joomla system, or PHP in general, I would recommend using an advanced editor like PHPStorm. One of its features is that it enables you to click on a class name to open up the PHP file for that class and see where it's located. 

If you combine PHPStorm with a debugger like Xdebug, you can also do things like step through the execution of the code line by line and see how it all works. It can take a bit of setting up depending on your environment, but it's worth the effort if you are planning to do much development work.

Comment: I don't understand, [use Joomla\CMS\Version] then linked to [..\libraries\src\Version.php], even the PATH doesn't seem similar to me, or are there some codes that facilitate the linking process ?, or should I read a document to understand this?

Comment: @dhanysaguntoro if you look at ..\administrator\cache\autoload_psr4.php in your Joomla installation you will see this file creates a map between the namespace and where the file actually resides. Each time certain extensions(component,library) are installed/updated then this file is deleted and regenerated based on the value in the <namespace> element in your manifest.xml. If you delete autoload_psr4.php then it will be regenerated the next time your website is invoked. Reading is good, try this https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/concepts.html#concepts-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Joomla uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) package manager to manage its dependencies and to autoload its classes. Composer autoloader follows [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading standard. In case you've never heard of these before, start by reading the linked documentation.

In short, Composer projects define their dependencies, autoloading rules and other project settings in a `composer.json` file. But Joomla CMS does not ship this file as the CMS doesn't (yet) support managing dependencies after installation (e.g. extensions can't use the top level Composer instance). You can see this file when running the CMS from a development environment, (i.e. from the [repository](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/)). In this file you'll find this `autoload` directive:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Joomla\\CMS\\": "libraries/src/"
    }
}
```

What it means is that classes in `libraries/src/` follow PSR-4 autoloading and have `Joomla\CMS\` namespace prefix. PSR-4 standard essentially maps class name to a file name, using namespace separator as directory separator and adding the `php` extension. Therefore, `Joomla\CMS\Version` class is mapped to `libraries/src/Version.php` file. And a deeper namespace class like `Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication` would be mapped to `libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php` file.

`Joomla\Utilities\IpHelper`, meanwhile, is not a class of the CMS but a class of a dependency. Particularly, [joomla/utilities](https://github.com/joomla-framework/utilities) package. It is required in the `composer.json` file of the CMS:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "joomla/application": "^2.0.4",
    "joomla/archive": "^2.0.2",
    "joomla/authentication": "^2.0.1",
    ...
    "joomla/utilities": "^2.0.1",
    ...
}
```

This package also has its own `composer.json` file which contains the `autoload` directive:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Joomla\\Utilities\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Normally Composer dependencies are installed in `vendor` directory but Joomla uses a custom directory defined using `vendor-dir` configuration option. Back in the `composer.json` of the CMS we can see this:

```
"config": {
     ...
    "vendor-dir": "libraries/vendor",
     ...
}
```

To build the path to classes of dependency packages, use the vendor directory (in this case `libraries/vendor`), package name (`joomla/utilities`) and the directory defined in the autoload configuration (`src/`). So ultimately, the root directory of `Joomla\Utilities` namespace is `libraries/vendor/joomla/utilities/src/`. And `Joomla\Utilities\IpHelper` class is in `libraries/vendor/joomla/utilities/src/IpHelper.php`.